# Web Applications Moderator Cards

Tags: discussion, design

We recently printed some business cards for our Stack Exchange employees and they turned out great.

It got us thinking: our sites' moderators have been working hard to keep our sites high quality for the past few years. They may not be employees, per se, but great community moderators are why our communities are safe, sane, and worth visiting in the first place..

If you're a webapps.stackexchange moderator, would you be interested in having your own Web Applications Stack Exchange contact card? Would you find it useful?

I can see them being handy to pass out during your local meetups or tech conferences.

Below is a mockup:

(click on image to see full res version)

[image: webapps.stackexchange.com moderator cards]

Of course Twitter ID/phone# are optional. It can be Skype, AIM, URL etc.

Note: the text rendering in the mockup is slightly blurry. But when printed it will be crisp.

Answer (score 6):

I think this is a brilliant idea - they would certainly come in handy at community events.

Was a decision made as to how the email address would work? Will it be a forwarding address from SE to our own personal email?

Comment: It will just be your personal email.

Comment: @Jin why is it not the "contact us" link below on the main WA site?

Answer (score 6):

I'd be interested too.

Having the cards would spur me on to find occasions where I can use them - in the first instance locally to get more "ordinary" users interested

Answer (score 4):

Quick question about these cards:

- How many will we receive
- What is the process for re-ordering. Do we pay for any subsequent orders?

Comment: you will receive one pack (50 cards). if you run out later, let us know. You don't pay.

Comment: @Jin: Thanks Jin

Answer (score 4):

OK, moderators have officially been mailed the form to obtain the cards. Stay tuned!